# Group an array to form three arrays based on the index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to sort an array in a way that it gives back three arrays. So

```
var myArray = ['1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3'];
```

here the values can be numbers, string, objects etc.

I want three arrays Like :

```
var myArray1 = ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'];
var myArray2 = ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'];
var myArray3 = ['3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3'];
```

Comment: Are you wanting to extract all the identical elements into separate arrays? Or are you wanting every third element to go into a different array? Your question isn't clear about that.

Comment: myArray1 should have values from index 1,4,7,10 ... 
myArray2 should have values from index 2,5,8,11 ...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. Stuck dont know how to start

Comment: Do you want to group based on the value or based on the index?

Comment: Yes I want every first,second and third element to go into a different array.

Comment: @adiga based on index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a generic function which will group the array based on the `n` provided. Based on the result of `index % n`, push them into specific arrays. Here, `n = 3`. If you use `i % 2`, this will distribute the numbers into 2 arrays based on odd and even indices.

```js
const myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'];

function group(array, n) {
  return myArray.reduce((acc, number, i) => {
    acc[i % n] = acc[i % n] || [];
    acc[i % n].push(number);
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

const grouped = group(myArray, 3);

console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped[0]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped[1]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped[2]))
```

Comment: I think the initial value of reduce should be `[]` instead of `{}`.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz both would work. That will create a 2D array. I'm creating an object with indexes from 0-2. I'll change it to `[]` because that better than objects with numeric index.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for high-order solution (using methods, like [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwix4pS-77TkAhVG1VkKHWWMAQIQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fuk%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AOvVaw1glOn11iPNhL5Zk4qh0eU0)) following approach might work:

```js
const arr = ['1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3'];

const [arr1,arr2,arr3] = arr.reduce((res,e,i) => (res[i%3].push(e),res), [[],[],[]]);

console.log(`arr1 = ${JSON.stringify(arr1)}`);
console.log(`arr2 = ${JSON.stringify(arr2)}`);
console.log(`arr3 = ${JSON.stringify(arr3)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

***p.s.*** got a sneak peek at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773809/11299053) (universal) solution to make mine a bit more compact

Comment: too tricky - (!(i%3), !((i-1)%3) etc. hard to read. since you already use reduce you can avail of an inner state - 0, 1, 2.

Comment: sure, please see my answer. you solution is good and will work, mine is more of an academical exercise. couple improvements - 1. the state doesn't have to be an array, 2. internal iterator looks neater and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = ['1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3'];

var myArray1 = [];
var myArray2 = [];
var myArray3 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length;) {
    myArray1.push(myArray [i++]); 
    myArray2.push(myArray [i++]);
    myArray3.push(myArray [i++]);
}
```